# Call different layouts based on function call

Tags: android

I have 2 functions send and receive. I need to display send and receive message. I have to display a.xml if it is send function and b.xml if it is received function. How can i set the flag. Please guide me how to call layouts based on function call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `setContentView(R.layout.a)` or `setContentView(R.layout.b)` to change the view hierarchy displayed by the activity. These can be called multiple times during an activity's life.